# How to generate a float between 1 and 100

Tags: swift, random

I am trying to generate random floats between 1 and 100, but I keep getting errors everytime. Currently I am trying:

```
func returnDbl ()-> Double {
    var randNum = Double(Float(arc4random(101) % 5))
    return randNum
}

print(returnDbl())
```

but to no avail, would someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: A `Float` or a `Double`?

Comment: its a function to return a double, so i am converting the float into a double

Answer (score 4):

`arc4random` is zero-based and returns values between 0 and n-1, pass 100 as the upper bounds and add 1

`arc4random_uniform` is easier to use, it returns an `Int32` type which has to be converted to `Float`.

```
func randomFloat() -> Float {
  return Float(arc4random_uniform(100) + 1)
}
```

or `Double`

```
func randomDouble() -> Double {
  return Double(arc4random_uniform(100) + 1)
}
```

or generic

```
func returnFloatingPoint<T : FloatingPointType>()-> T {
  return T(arc4random_uniform(100) + 1)
}

let float : Float = returnFloatingPoint()
let double : Double = returnFloatingPoint()
```

**Edit**

To return a non-integral Double between 1.000000 and 99.99999 with `arc4random_uniform()` use

```
func returnDouble()-> Double {
  return Double(arc4random_uniform(UInt32.max)) / 0x100000000 * 99.0 + 1.0
}
```

`0x100000000` is `UInt32.max + 1`

Comment: i had an answer similar to this, but when i tried to convert it to a float, it gave me an error, the overall goal is to have a float between 1 and 100

Comment: this will never return 100. arc4random_uniform(99) will generate a number from 0-98 + 1 the maximum number you will get is 99

Comment: Thank you for the note, @LeoDabus

Comment: This generates random integers between 1 and 100 that just happen to be cast to a float or double.

Comment: I updated the answer again to return non-integral doubles.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH DUDE, but now i have to ask this question (I like to understand the answers and not just take them) whats the difference between UINT32_MAX and Uint32.max?

Comment: There is no difference, it contains the same value. `UINT32_MAX` is a global computed variable to be compatible to the ObjC macro, `UInt32.max` calls the type property `max`

Answer (score 2):

```
let a = 1 + drand48() * 99
```

`drand48` is a C function that returns a `double` in the range [0, 1). You can call it directly from Swift. Multiplying by `99` gives you a `double` in the range [0, 99). Add one to get into the range [1, 100).

As `drand48` returns a `double`, the Swift type will be `Double`.

---

As per the comment, `drand48` will by default return the same sequence of numbers upon every launch. You can avoid that by seeding it. E.g.

```
seed48(UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>([arc4random(), arc4random()]))
```

Comment: what would my setup be though? I am still trying to get the hang of swift, still a swift newbie, im about 4 days into it

Comment: right now this is what i have but its not giving me what i want which is random floats between 1 and 100, its just giving me floats between 0 and 1
func returnDbl ()-> Double{
    var randNum = Double(Float(arc4random() % 101) / 50)
return randNum
}
print(returnDbl())

Comment: This solution always returns the same number when I test in a Playground. Doesn't it need to be "seeded"?

Comment: ive tweaked it to an answer that soneon gave me, but its just returning doubles, i was trying to read through the documentation, and i see theres the UINT32_MAX , someone told me that i could use that to get the results i want, but im confused as to how i would set that up

Comment: If you want it to return a different sequence of numbers from every launch then it needs to be seeded. `seed48` is the thing.

Comment: Im not the negative voter, i just wanted to say that the number doesnt seem to be random each time i do it, its the same number everytime i hit run it. Is there a reason for that?
the number is ;
40.2500126022673

Comment: @TonyBlack I've switched the proposed seed; taking an int16 pointer into a double clearly produces three int16s but the random seed just isn't going to change much between runs — the whole mantissa is likely to be the same, and most of the fractional part is going to be similar. So I've switched to using `arc4random` as a more robust random number generator that doesn't need seeding.

Answer (score -1):

```
func returnDbl ()-> Double {
    var randNum = Double(Float(arc4random() % 101))
    return randNum
}
```

Comment: this only returns doubles, i need floats to show. Thats where the problem is, i can do doubles easily, but it seems like i cant convert floats into doubles, is there a way to do this with the UINT32_MAX method?

Answer (score -1):

Ok thank you everybody for all of your help, the setups you showed me helped me figure out how the setup should at least look, my end result is

func returnDbl ()-> Double{
    var randNum = Double(Float(arc4random_uniform(99)+1)) / Double(UINT32_MAX)
return randNum
}
print(returnDbl())

it returns floats between 1 and 100.

Comment: this will never return 100. arc4random_uniform(99) will generate a number from 0-98 + 1 the maximum number you will get is 99

Comment: but i want there to be a huge number of possibilities in between so litterally 4 billion possibilities is ok with me

Comment: Here's the kind of result I get with this "solution": `6.51925802382623e-09`, `1.86264514966464e-09`, `2.11875885774353e-08`...

Comment: it seems right but maybe im not seeing what your saying clearly. I want to generate results between 1 - 100, and they have to be floats, but im returning a double and it has to be random. You say this doesnt do it but it seems like it does to me, what exactly is wrong? Im open to any and all suggestions, i am still new to this

Comment: I see what you're saying, my highest result is 9.54605639203127e-09, what suggestions do you have for me to alter my code?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to not do cargo cult operations. What I mean is don't divide by UINT32_MAX if you don't know why you would do that. My second suggestion would be to study @tommy's answer which I believe is the only one properly answering your request. Note that your question and comments weren't very clear so i'm not surprised by the content of the other answers being slightly off-topic (they're right, but still off-topic). IMHO.

Comment: thank you for that, im still trying to figure it out Tommy's answer, i just dont understand his answer

Comment: I could explain but I don't want to hijack @tommy's answer. You can ask him for details and explanations. :)

Comment: I did, im jus asking him why the random number is the same number every time i run it, im just waiting for his response

Comment: Im actually new to this site, mi not 100% sure how it works, a whole bunch of ups and downs and voting systems and im jus like @_@ too much!!!! lol

Comment: Don't worry, you''ll get used to it. :) Read the Help center if you're lost, there's lots of infos. // I just wanted to add that @vadian has made an excellent update to his answer. You may find it easier to use than Tommy's one (which is still valid, of course).